# formatting only effecting right side of display block

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, erb

My CSS mirrors the CSS for chapter 11 in hartl but for some reason, the avatars for my followers are lining up vertically instead of horizontally and each column has a line separating them. Like this :

[image]

The way it is supposed to look is vertical rows with no lines separating them. Like this :

[image]

I am more than happy to share any details that could prove helpful! thanks in advance!

Here is my CSS :

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Atomic+Age|Raleway);
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  /*font-family: 'Atomic Age', cursive;*/
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $grayLight;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}


/* header */

#logo {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid $grayMediumLight;
  color: $grayLight;
  a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover {
      color: $grayDarker;
    }
  }
  small {
    float: left;
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
  }
}

/* miscellaneous */

.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

/* sidebar */

aside {
  section {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    &:first-child {
      border: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    span {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.4em;
      text-align: left;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  }
}

.stats {
  overflow: auto;
  a {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    color: gray;
    &:first-child {
      padding-left: 0;
      border: 0;
    }
    &:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: $blue;
    }
  }
  strong {
    display: block;
  }
}

.user_avatars {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  .gravatar {
    margin: 1px 1px;
  }
}

/* forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

input {
  height: auto !important;
}

#error_explanation {
  color: #f00;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 18px 0;
  }
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .control-group;
  @extend .error;
}

/* Users index */

.users {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  li {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    &:last-child {
      border-bottom: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    }
  }
}

/* microposts */

.microposts {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;

  li {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  }
}
.content {
  display: block;
}
.timestamp {
  color: $grayLight;
}
.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
aside {
  textarea {
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

Here is my show_follow.html.erb :

```
<% provide(:title, @title) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
      <span><%= link_to "view my profile", @user %></span>
      <span><b>Microposts:</b> <%= @user.microposts.count %></span>
    </section>
    <section>
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
      <% if @users.any? %>
        <div class="user_avatars">
          <% @users.each do |user| %>
            <%= link_to gravatar_for(user, size: 30), user %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="span8">
    <h3><%= @title %></h3>
    <% if @users.any? %>
      <ul class="users">
        <%= render @users %>
      </ul>
      <%= will_paginate %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help if you can, thank you!

Comment: Can I see how your html looks for the avatars?

Comment: The `show_follow.html.erb` I have posted is where the html that is generating the avatars is located. It is running through an `each do` loop with a class `user_avatars` which is also posted in the description. It is defined in my CSS posted above. Do you want to see a different view?

Comment: Yeah could I see how it the html looks once it has been generated?

Comment: The first picture on the top is how it looks once it has been generated

Answer (score 0):

Give an explicit width to the mother `<section>` of `.user_avatar` class like `300px` or something and make `display:block`. Apply `display:inline-block` to `.user_avatars` and also create a `:before` class for that `<section>` and put a `display:block` in it.